# UIActivityViewController returns "completed" as true even if the user cancelled the activity

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

UIActivityViewController returns "completed" as true even if the user cancelled the activity

We are using UIActivityViewController to share a URL and text from our application. We use the completion block as defined below to detect whether the activity successfully completed or not.

```
UIActivityViewController *shareActivity = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[ textActivity, urlActivity ] applicationActivities:nil];  

[shareActivity setCompletionWithItemsHandler:^(UIActivityType __nullable activityType, BOOL completed, NSArray *__nullable returnedItems, NSError *__nullable activityError) {  
    if (activityError) {  
        // show an alert  
        return;  
    }  
    if (completed && activityType) {  
        // track the activity type  
        // show an alert          
    }
}];
```

As shown in the above code, we show an alert so that the user understands that the activity is completed. We also track the activity that was done. The above code works perfectly fine for posting to applications like Twitter, Facebook, Mail, Message, Notes, Slack etc. But for some activities mentioned below it fails because the completed flag comes as "true" even though the user has cancelled the activity:

Failing Activities:

- Reminders (iOS stock application)
- Outlook mail application
- WhatsApp

There might be more applications which might be failing but I was able to find above applications since I have them installed on my device.

Is there anyway to fix this problem?

Comment: no way to fix this. you should customize your own control. that is better. apple uikit is crap.

Answer (score 0):

Instagram, WhatsApp and Messenger fails to send false when cancelled. Your code is alright.

I've just submitted a bug to completely fix your (also my) problem :) https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/727214027651581/?disable_redirect=0

Wait and hope.